# BITMAPFILEHEADER.bfSize doesn't match the file size?

Tags: winapi, bitmap

Reading the specs for `BITMAPFILEHEADER` structure says `bfSize` is the number of bytes in the file.

But when I look at a .bmp file here on my drive it's actually 2 bytes smaller than the file size?  Is that just a mistake or does it not count the `bfType` ?  I've seen other examples where it matches the size?

Comment: "*Is that just a mistake*" - yes."*does it not count the `bfType`*" - yes, `bfType` is included in  `bfSize`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see that on others, this other bitmap must be compressed, does that change anything?

Comment: no. Compression only applies to the pixel data, not any of the various headers.